# Custom taxonomy with custom post type template not showing

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, templates

I have registered custom taxonomy:

```
add_action('init', 'registerCustomTaxonomies');
function registerCustomTaxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'products',
        'product', [
            'label' => 'Product Categories',
            'has_archive' => false,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'rewrite' => [
                'slug' => 'products',
            ],
        ]
    );
}

add_action('init', 'addTaxonomiesToPages');
function addTaxonomiesToPages() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('products', 'product');
}

flush_rewrite_rules();
```

And I have created file `taxonomy-products.php` but I'm getting **Not found** when I'm going to `http://example.com/products`

Comment: you flush the rewrite rules too early and it's not good to do that on every page load. remove this call and flush them with the permalink page.

Comment: @mmm Ok, I have do this but still nothing

Comment: Are there even any products yet? When there are no products, it will result in a "Not found".

Comment: @swissspidy It has subcategories (it's totaly 3-levels)

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. Are there any products in these subcategories?

Comment: No, nothing at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php file is an Archive Template and not a good name for a custom template. So if you want to proceed with a custom template, try naming the file with something like template-cities.php and call the file to a Page.

Otherwise, make a simple taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php archive template, and in your case taxonomy-city.php with code like:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="page_content">
    <div class="page-wrapper">
        <div id="page_content_wrapper">
            <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
                <div id="careers_table">
                    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                        <p class="content_text"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php // pagination code here ?>
                </div>
            <?php else : ?>
                <div class="post">
                    <h3><?php _e('No City Found', 'cmeasytheme'); ?></h3>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div> <!-- .page_content_wrapper -->
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div> <!-- .page-wrapper -->
</div> <!-- .page_content -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>

<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'custom-taxonomy-name', '<footer class="entry-meta"><span class="tag-links">', '', '</span></footer>' ); ?>
```